# append mode in Centos and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, r

Both my systems show the very same permissions on the file.

```
-rw-r--r--
```

I have a script running in R that uses a basic R function

```
download.file('http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-100-rows.csv', '/home/rstudio/xyz9', mode = "a", quiet = FALSE)
```

`mode="a"` means append mode.

I run the scrit on local system through Rstudio(IDE for R). It appends the files on my ubuntu system which is the local system.

I run this script on server which is a centos through RStudio only and instead of appending data to the file, it completely overwrites the file.

Is that a problem on system level or script level? permissions look just fine to me .

When I run it on the server, I get the following on console:

```
--2016-07-13 19:28:23--  http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-100-rows.csv
Resolving www.sample-videos.com... 52.74.31.185
Connecting to www.sample-videos.com|52.74.31.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/csv]
Saving to: “/home/rstudio/xyz9”

     0K ..........                                              267M=0s

2016-07-13 19:28:24 (267 MB/s) - “/home/rstudio/xyz9” saved [10998]
```

When I run it on ubuntu, I get:

```
trying URL 'http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-100-rows.csv'
downloaded 10 KB
```

What could be wrong here? I do really want the append mode to work on centos machine. Since I am running exactly the same script, I believe this has something to do with file permissions?

Edit:
As I see, Modified date is a little messed up on the centos machine. It's a server and hosted remotely. 
I see weird time stamp for split of a second when the file is updated.

At 7:43, It shows modified date be :

5:56 p.m (same date).

When I run the download.file function,

file size for a moment becomes 0 Kb.
Modified date changed to correct time for a moment.
After update, modified date changed to 6:40 p.m

Time has been correctly set on the centos system.

What seems not to work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be problem with permissions. You can write and read data, that's all, but program has to decide how to work with data inside a file. It looks like R, not system, problem to me.

Anyway, outputs from server and local host are different. The one from server looks same like from `wget`. Check `download.file.method` which have to be set to `internal` (according to [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html)) - only this method support appending to file.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. What does it exactly mean to have the method set to internal or curl or wget? How does that make any difference here?

Comment: I'm not R expert, just reading documentation :) (lib)curl, wget, lynx, etc. are external libraries/programs, which R can use to get a specific benefits which don't want to implement. I guess..

Comment: I need append mode to work with https url as well. How would that be? internal method does not seem to support https urls